# Set CPU affinity for specific VM on VMware ESXI using govc CLI

Tags: vmware, esxi, affinity, govmomi

I have shell scripts that I use to programmatically configure my virtual machines (VMs) on my **VMware** **ESXi** host. I use the "**govc**" command-line-interface (CLI) which provides a suite of commands to configure my VMs that run on my ESXI (i.e., powering on, setting ram, etc...)

*I am trying now to set the CPU affinity for some of my virtual machines* (i.e., VM #2 should use CPUs 9-16 whereas VM#1 should use CPU 2-8). *However*, I **cannot**  find any govc command to do this programmatically, though I can very clearly see how to do this within the ESXI web-based GUI:

[image]

I reference the **govc** API for commands here, but again, I could not find anything. The CPU affinity should be set for a specific VM, and there should be an argument of CPU numbers separated by comma or with hyphen (-) for a range, I would imagine:

*[govc usage](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/blob/master/govc/USAGE.md)*

How can I fix this problem with VMware ESXi and govc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Kyle Ruddy stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65793123/set-cpu-affinity-for-specific-vm-on-vmware-esxi-using-govc-cli/65829249#65829249), it couldn't be done via govc, but it can be done by finding your .VMX file for your respective VM on the ESXi datastore and simply add this line to your `.vmx`  file.

```
sched.cpu.affinity = 1,2,3,4,5 // Values are separated by commas
```

You can double check your ESXi, by selecting the VM and going into its settings and you will see the *CPU Scheduled Affinity Range* that you set via the VMX file.

Of course , if you have a lot of CPUs, you can have some script (Bash, etc.) with a *for* loop populate the comma-delimited CPU values.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a configuration that's been enabled at the govc level, as Doug mentioned in [your issue](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/issues/2246).

Alternatively, you could use other CLIs, like PowerCLI which is PowerShell based, and has a lot more coverage area for more in-depth tasks like this, or the govmomi SDK, which has full API coverage.